# Calling Unmanaged DLL from VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, unmanaged

I'm having some trouble finding the syntax for making function calls to unmanaged DLLs in VB.NET. Is anyone familiar with this?

Let's just assume there's a function "Connected" in unmanaged DLL "Connector.DLL". I want to call this function by creating an abstract function call to it.

I've seen some code out there that looks something like

```
[DllImport("Connector.DLL")]
Public Shared Function Connect(ByVal intPort)
```

But that syntax doesn't work for me.

Comment: Looks like you are using an incorrect syntax for the attribute. Attributes in VB need to be included in angle brackets and must be on the same line as the function declaration. Check out MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) or http://pinvoke.net for samples.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
Public Declare Function Connect Lib "Connector.DLL" (<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal intPort As Integer) As Integer
```

Answer (score -2):

In Visual Studio, add a reference to this Dll.

In Code:

```
Dim vr as new COMDllClass()
vr.FunctionInDll()
```

**EDIT per comment:**

Try this code:

```
<DllImport("Connector.DLL")> _
Public Shared Function Connect(ByVal intPort)
```

Comment: Unmanaged DLLs aren't applicable as visual studio references.

Comment: So this is not even a COM visible DLL? Then you'll likely need to write a COM wrapper and call that from Visual Basic.